What is homotopy relative to in homotopically equivalent topological spaces?

Two spaces $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent if there are continuous maps $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $g: Y \rightarrow X$ with $gf \sim \textbf{1}_X$ and $fg \sim \textbf{1}_Y$.

Before this section, homotopy of two functions between two topological spaces relative to a set was defined as existence of a function which is having some properties. Relevant to my question however, is only the fact that homotopy was defined relative to a set. In the above definition of homotopy equivalence of the topological space. What exactly are these homotopy equivalences relative too?

The empty set. Does your text not define a non-relative notion of homotopy?

Not to my knowledge @BenSteffan

What text is this?

The notion of homotopy here is that of free homotopy. The homotopies in question are not required to fix any subspace; equivalently, they are relative to the empty space.
